# Can somebody please explain to me what I am doing wrong here? It's part of a worksheet that isn't particularly clear

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import sys

print("(\\(\\")
print("(-.-)")
print("o_(\")(\")")
player_name = input("what is your name? \n")

def print_hello(name) : 
        print(f"greetings peasant {name}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(0)
```

As far as I am aware, the output from the above should be:

```
What is your name? 
(input)
Greetings Peasant (input)..
```

I only get as far as answering "what is your name"

Comment: You never call `print_hello()`, you exit with `sys.exit(0)`.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't calling the function

```
def print_hello(name): 
  print(f"greetings peasant {name}")

def main():
  print("(\\(\\")
  print("(-.-)")
  print("o_(\")(\")")
  player_name = input("what is your name? \n")
  print_hello(player_name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Comment: Thanks this worked great. Please ignore the random prints. Apparently that was a tutor "trying to be cute??" idk.

I do have another question, what is the relevance of main() here? Is it just closing out the main function? I wish I could show you this worksheet. The answer you gave makes it look ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

You defined a function `print_hello` but you never really called it.

Try this instead:

```
print("(\\(\\")
print("(-.-)")
print("o_(\")(\")")
player_name = input("what is your name? \n")

def print_hello(name) : 
  print(f"greetings peasant {name}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
  print_hello(player_name)
```